# Google Sheets: The reference to entity "Wheel-TW" must end with the ';' delimiter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the following script in a Google Apps deployment of a Google Sheets document to build and update a RSS feed database with all the new items that are published every week.

```
function getURLData() {
 
  var currentData = [];
  var urltoCheck = [
    "https://agremia.com/feed",
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < urltoCheck.length; i++){
  var ficiencaData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urltoCheck[i]);
  var xml = ficiencaData.getContentText()
  let response = XmlService.parse(xml);
  var root = response.getRootElement();
   let channel = root.getChild('channel');
  let items = channel.getChildren('item');
    items.forEach(item => {
      let title = item.getChild('title').getText();
      let pubDateb = item.getChild('pubDate').getText();
      let link = item.getChild('link').getText();
      currentData.push([title,pubDateb,link,urltoCheck[i]])
   
  });
};;;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Combinado Medios");
  var currentDataRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, currentData.length, currentData[0].length);
  currentDataRange.setValues(currentData); 
  
}
```

I have been using this for a good week and it worked just fine. Now I am getting th following error, which I don't really know how to fix

```
Exception: Error on line 134: The reference to entity "Wheel-TW" must end with the ';' delimiter. getURLData    @ code new.gs:24
```

It's strange because there is no such thing as a Wheel-TW entity, so I don't understand what the error in the code might be. I've tried applying some of the solutions mentioned in similar questions but none have worked so far.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When I tested your showing script, no error occurs. The values of `currentData` is correctly put into the cells. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. From this situation, can I ask you about the detail of the method for correctly replicating your current issue? In this case, first, I would like to correctly replicate it.

Comment: @Tanaike, you may check the code in this Google Sheets document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CuU1sTy8ROsNhBAqsapjHnm1vdbyMHf76EcPnRwKIQ0/edit?usp=sharing
All I did was: 1) rename sheet to Combinado Medios; 2) create new Google Apps script; 3) Paste the code; 4) Rename, give permission, save and run.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your provided Spreadsheet, I understood your current issue. So, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. But, if your URLs are not the URLs in your provided Spreadsheet, another issue might occur. I'm worried about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your following reply,

> you may check the code in this Google Sheets document: docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/… All I did was: 1) rename sheet to Combinado Medios; 2) create new Google Apps script; 3) Paste the code; 4) Rename, give permission, save and run.

When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, I noticed that the including script is different from your showing script. In your showing script in your question, only one URL is used. But, when I tested your actual script, I noticed that the URL of your issue is different from that of your showing script. From this situation, when I tested your actual script, I could know the reason for your current issue.

When your showing script is modified, please modify it as follows.

#### From:

```
var xml = ficiencaData.getContentText()
```

#### To:

```
var xml = ficiencaData.getContentText().replace(/&/g, "&amp;");
```

When this modification is reflected in your showing script, it becomes as follows.

```js
function getURLData() {
  var currentData = [];
  var urltoCheck = ["URL1", "URL2",,,"URL14"]; // Please set your actual 14 URLs.
  for (var i = 0; i < urltoCheck.length; i++) {
    var ficiencaData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urltoCheck[i]);
    var xml = ficiencaData.getContentText().replace(/&/g, "&amp;");
    let response = XmlService.parse(xml);
    var root = response.getRootElement();
    let channel = root.getChild('channel');
    let items = channel.getChildren('item');
    items.forEach(item => {
      let title = item.getChild('title').getText();
      let pubDateb = item.getChild('pubDate').getText();
      let link = item.getChild('link').getText();
      currentData.push([title, pubDateb, link, urltoCheck[i]])
    });
  };
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Combinado Medios");
  var currentDataRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, currentData.length, currentData[0].length);
  currentDataRange.setValues(currentData);
}
```

- When I tested this modified script using your 14 URLs, I confirmed no error.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you for the explanation. It helped me understand the issue much better.

Comment: @djur Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could understand the reason for the issue with your cooperation. Thank you, too.